# How to check more than 1 property of object have value

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I have a class with n properties, and I need to know if more than 1 property has value, it will be false, I write a method like this *CheckValue*

```
 public class ClassExample
    {
        public ClassExample(string value1, string value2, string value3)
        {
            Value1 = value1;
            Value2 = value2;
            Value3 = value3;
            if (CheckValue()) throw new Exception("Not allow set value for both Value1, Value2, Value3");
        }
        public string Value1 { get;  }
        public string Value2 { get;  }
        public string Value3 { get; }

        public bool CheckValue()
        {
            if ((Value1 != null ? 1 : 0) +
                (Value2 != null ? 1 : 0) +
                (Value3 != null ? 1 : 0) > 1)
            {
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
    }
```

Are there any better way to write CheckValue method?

Comment: You might get better feedback from codereview

Comment: That would check all the properties. You could do a short-circuit using `if (Value1 != null || Value2 != null || Vaule3 != null)`. If you want to micro-optimize, you could put first the most common assigned property...

Comment: Another way would be using https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: I just want to find the simplest way to do that. and prevent change code if 1 property is added. Actually I will but this method in the constructor and remove set. Look my update question

Comment: Check the propertychanged event, that way you yould not have to remember to add code to the CheckValue method.

Comment: Yes...don’t allow null strings

Comment: This is best suited to code review. For your constructor a nice trick would be `public ClassExample(params string[] values)`  and checking for values length.For the properties, I would have a private counter of assigned values and on property assignment increment or decrement it

Comment: Instead of asking what solution you are looking for, maybe you should describe your problem. That solution looks smelly, and maybe it would be better to approach the problem in a entirely different way.

Comment: _This looks like a job for Code Generation!_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the following. For sake of example, am assuming your properties in concern are named with pattern Value_. You could alter the search filter as required.

```
public bool CheckValue()
{
       return this.GetType().GetProperties()
               .Where(property=> property.Name.StartsWith("Value"))
               .Count(property=>property.GetValue(this,null)!=null)>=1;

}
```

If you do not want to filter the properties, you could do the following.

```
 return `this.GetType().GetProperties().Count(property=>property.GetValue(this,null)!=null)>=1;
```

You might also have to identify expected/default value of value type as well and add the checks for same as well, as this the query above checks only for null values. 
But please be aware of the performance implication of using reflection`.

Comment: You *could*, you probably *shouldn't*.

Comment: Yes, I agree. Just added the option since the OP had mentioned n properties, and a non-reflection approach might turn ugly if there are a lot of properties. May be I will add that as a comment in Answer too

Comment: My property name is random is not "value"

Comment: @GreyWolf Do you want to check all the properties or some of the properties in the class ?

Comment: Yes, all property, my sample just give 3 for easy, later it will be un-know

Comment: Thank, I will choose your answer if dont have any better answer and I will test it

Comment: Thanks, I don't know there is CodeReview :)

Comment: Added an answer without reflection, but there are some interesting alternatives, like property changed events that would work pretty good if the properties have public setters.

Comment: I choose this is right answer because it's simple and can solve my problem (dont need update code when add or remove property). May be it's not the best but I think it better than my solution in question

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all properties are same type, or that all are nullable. You could use `params`:

```
 public class ClassExample
    {
        public ClassExample(params string[] values)
        {
            if (values == null || values.Count(p => p != null) != 1) throw new ArgumentException("Just 1 value please");
            if (values.Length > 0) Value1 = values[0];
            if (values.Length > 1) Value2 = values[1];
            // rest of property assignments;
        }
        public string Value1 { get; private set; }
        public string Value2 { get; private set; }
        public string Value3 { get; private set; }

    }
}
```